# Using a figure imported through a package

Tags: includegraphics

I have a figure that I want to use in a package to create some commands, and I'd like to specify the path for `includegraphics` relative to the package directory, instead of the full path.

Right now the command in the package file is defined as

```
\includegraphics{<absolute_path_to_the_figure>}
```

which is not ideal if I want to change the location of my packages or if I need to port it to another machine. How can I change it to

```
\includegraphics{<current_path_the_package_file>/<figure_name>}
```

Comment: You shouldn’t need to specify the path provided the package folder itself is findable.

Comment: Oh, didn't think it was that simple

Answer (score 1):

In `graphics` package, `\graphicspath` command is available which set default path to search graphics file. You can use it like this:

```
\graphicspath{{<current path to graphics directory>/}} % in preamble
...
\includegraphics{<graphic file name>}
```

That is equal to

```
\includegraphics{<current path to graphics directory>/<graphic file name>}
```

Moreover, you can set directory list by `\graphicspath` command:

```
\graphicspath{{<dir 1>/}{<dir 2>/}{<dir 3>/}}
```

Also, I take your attention of `\includegraphics`, by default, searches image files through same paths those are used by `\input@path`. So if your package is loaded by `\usepackage` command, graphic files placed on the same directory with `.sty` file will be found by `\includegraphics` without any additional path specification.